# Realtime Updates to Text Area as Changes Occur in Input Boxes

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a page that lets me auto complete a document for use elsewhere.

I have multiple input boxes and eventually multiple drop down boxes that each represent a variable inside the large body of text. After selecting, or sticking with the default selected, the text can be copied out to another location for use.

Right now I have this and it somewhat works for text boxes but has a lot of issues:

Below is what I currently use and can easily enough expand it out to multiple input boxes however if I click anywhere inside the textarea or try to rechange the text after making the initial change of any of the input boxes it no longer works because the variable is missing.

```
<script>
function tst(elm){
    var trgt=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    trgt.value=trgt.value.replace(elm.getAttribute('name'), elm.value);
}
</script>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" onblur="tst(this);" />
    <input type="text" name="whoisthis" onblur="tst(this);" />
    <input type="text" name="positionwithin" onblur="tst(this);" />
    <textarea style="width:500px; height: 100px;" name="result">Hello, firstname

 I am writing to inform you that whoisthisis no longer available for the position of positionwithin. They finished 4th.</textarea>
</form>
```

What I am trying to accomplish, and failing at so far, is being able to manipulate the fields, if needed multiple times for it to show the changes and to add the ability to use drop down boxes such as 4th being changable to 1st, 2nd or whatever other number or text is needed.

Comment: This kind of stuff is a piece of cake for reactive JS frameworks like React, Vue, Svelte, etc. Are you using one or have a reason not to?

Comment: why would you want to do it using the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to achieve it, but using your way it should be like this.

```
<form action="#">

    <input type="text" name="firstname" onblur="testFunction(this)" />
    <input type="text" name="whoisthis" onblur="testFunction(this)" />
    <input type="text" name="positionwithin" onblur="testFunction(this)" />

    <textarea name="result">Hello, firstname

I am writing to inform you that whoisthis is no longer available for the position of positionwithin. They finished 4th.
    </textarea>

</form>

<script>
    const trgt = document.querySelector("textarea")

    const testFunction = (elm) => {
        trgt.value = trgt.value.replace(elm.name, elm.value)
    }
</script>
```

- `trgt` is the `textarea`
- `testFunction` is the function that is responsible for changing the text
- `elm` is the input element passed in the parameter
- `elm.name` and `elm.value` represents name and value attribute of the input

Comment: How would you recommend I do this, what would be the better way?

Comment: It depends upon what is the use of text. Like if the text stays the same always, you can set it after the request has been posted. Otherwise you can ask the user if they want default text or custom text, and verify if the custom text was submitted then use custom instead of default and vice versa. There are other workarounds depending upon the logic. If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as an accepted answer